# What does “produce” mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> The jetties coming out into the river, and a host of ships in the Middle Ages, little wooden ships ferrying *produce* across from the Continent and back. [<sub>(Source)</sub>](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=the-great-british-story-a-peoples-history-2012&episode=s01e03)

The structure of the whole sentence is quite confusing to me: how can I understand it?

I looked it up [here](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/produce). I would have picked the fourth meaning,

> if you produce an object, you bring it out or present it, so that people can see or consider it
>
> > When challenged, he produced a gun.

But produce is not transitive in my example.

Comment: Which dictionaries have you consulted?  Do you think that word is a noun or a verb?

Comment: @JamesK Thanks for commenting. I looked it up [here](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/produce). I would have picked the fourth meaning, if *produce* is not transitive there.

Comment: @benny - Scroll down at that dictionary link and look for the noun definition (main definition 2).  It should make a lot more sense.

Comment: @Benny I've incorporated your comment into the question.  It is now clear why you are confused. Remember you can edit your questions, instead of adding information in comments.

Comment: Your problem was confusion about "produce", but the sentence doesn't make sense to me. If the second comma was a colon, the sentence could be a list of two things with the meaning "Jetties, and boats: clarification about boats".

Comment: I can't find that sentence at the source you linked to. When I search for "jetties", the sentence ends at "in the Middle Ages", there's nothing about produce.

Comment: @Barmar I also have no idea, because it’s an edited version by another user, although at a glance the context is quite indeed about what I was asking.

Comment: Where did you find the quote in the first place? Maybe you can fix the link.

Comment: @Barmar A documentary, as I mentioned in the comments. But I may think doing so is not very much in need, the answers below are already sufficient and perfect for one to get a good understanding about this topic.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You've got to scroll down further on your definition page to:

[image: Definition of produce]

> **prod-uce**: noun [uncountable]
>     food or other things that have been grown or produced on a farm to be sold

You see that produce can also be a noun, so it means crops, food, or other things produced on a farm (and, might I add, elsewhere as well.)

Therefore, the sentence means:

> The jetties coming out into the river, and a host of ships in the Middle Ages, little wooden ships ferrying *things produced on farms* across from the Continent and back.

Comment: Worthwhile to note, as the link does, that the two are generally pronounced differently. The verb is with a short O, the noun is with a long O.

Comment: @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain Indeed. It's one of the many [Initial-stress derived nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial-stress-derived_noun) in English.

Comment: And you don't really need to scroll down to discover that it has multiple meanings: the top of the page contains a listing of its "word family", including a link to the noun "produce".

Comment: In my experience with modern American English, it typically refers to fruits and vegetables.

Comment: Would it seem strange to use "produce" for other things you might buy when getting your groceries? Laundry detergent, diesel, tissue paper, glue, etc.

Comment: It would seem very strange. Produce means things you would get from a farm, generally whatever is sold by a greengrocer and most of what is sold by a butcher, plus a few other related goods. @Wilson

Comment: @Wilson those are "products" not "produce". Once it's processed from its raw state, it becomes a product.

Answer (score 14):

The reason that you are confused is that "produce" (with the stress on the second syllable) is a verb. But "produce" (with the stress on the first syllable) is a noun, and it is the noun that is being used here.

In this context "produce" means "fresh food, vegetables, etc"; basically anything you get from a farm. It is a non-count noun. So your quote can be glossed:

> ... little wooden ships carrying food across to the continent and back.

If I remember my history I think that wine was carried from France to England, and wool was taken from England to France.

Comment: Yes, pointing out that difference in pronunciation here is important.

Comment: @Lambie aha, it’s actually a documentary, and I listened to it again. Indeed, *the street is on the second syllable*! I just missed that point!

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: [xkcd 859](https://xkcd.com/859/)

Comment: @JamesK what's that？

Comment: @benny, a joke, in reply to Kat's comment.

Answer (score 3):

I think a bit part of the problem is that the whole passage has no main verb: it isn't a well-formed sentence, but rather a verbless sentence fragment; one long noun-phrase describing a scene. "Ferrying" is a verb but is active only within a subordinate part; and "produce" as has been noted is here as a noun.

I see that it's from a script. It's common in stage directions to have descriptions of what is to be shown: "A man's apartment, with a window facing trees, and a writing desk on the left". So that's what this is. It's a nice word-picture, rather like we're zooming slowly in what might be a still picture, and then realizing that the boats are actually moving.

Comment: It's not a stage direction, it seems to be part of a list of things that the narrator is describing.

Comment: I think CCTO is saying that this fragment from a documentary script is *like* a stage direction, not that it *is* one.